# ¿Como puedo mostrar un aviso de que hay una nueva actualizacion en una app privada?

Tags: flutter, programación-móvil, google-play, google-play-console

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Flutter, pero se subió a la Play Store como una app privada. Para realizar la acción de mostrar un mensaje al usuario para la actualización, estoy utilizando la librería https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader, pero me arroja el siguiente mensaje en la consola `I/flutter (26207): upgrader: Can't find an app in the Play Store with the id: my.app.id`.
A mi entender, creo que no la encuentra por que esta como privada, por que si puedo encontrar la aplicación cuando la busco desde la cuenta de la organización.

Si ese es el caso, ¿Cómo puedo avisarle al usuario que existe una nueva actualización? o no es posible?

Comment: Podrías crear una tabla donde almacenes las versiones de la app, y la vas comparando, luego dependiendo de la consulta que hagas desde la app, podrías mostrar un cuadro de diálogo en el main

Comment: @JonathanPerez Suena bien la idea, la probare cuando tenga la oportunidad, gracias

Comment: Concuerdo con Jonathan, creo que es buena opción tener en algún sitio, online, la último versión de la app. Al iniciar la app, lo primero que deberías hacer es comprobar qué versión tiene tu app y si es diferente de la última versión que tengas almacenada. Y si no está actualizada, mostrar algún mensaje o pantalla específica para informar al usuario.